# ODE Solver Implementation for f(t, x, u)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Recently I've been learning about solving DEs numerically. In order to understand various methods, I've implemented some of them in Julia. So far I have implementations to solve a system of DEs of the form
$$
\dot x(t) = f(t, x(t)) \quad \text{where } x\in\mathbb{R}^n.
$$

I've used the Runge-Kutta method, which computes the following:
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n + \Delta t \sum\limits_{i=1}^s b_i k_i
$$
where
$$
k_i = f(t_n + c_i \Delta t, x_n + \Delta t \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} k_i a_{ij})
$$

Now I want to implement a solver for a system of DEs of the form
$$
\dot x(t) = f(t, x(t), u(t)) \quad \text{where } x\in\mathbb{R}^n, u\in\mathbb{R}^m
$$
in order to solve controlled dynamical systems, where $x$ and $u$ are the state and control input vectors, respectively. Therefore, one would need to solve the DE over a given time interval. I see two options in order to do solve the DE for the last equation:

###### Option 1

Using a constant value for $u(t)$ within one time step where the DE is solved, i.e.: $u(t)$ is constant within $[t, t + \Delta t)$. Therefore, I'd calculate
$$
k_i = f(t_n + c_i \Delta t, x_n + \Delta t \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} k_i a_{ij}, u(t)),
$$
or

###### Option 2

using a continuous time controller, where $u$ is interpolated somehow, but how?
$$
k_i = f(t_n + c_i \Delta t, x_n + \Delta t \sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1} k_i a_{ij}, ...)
$$

Is there a method for that? How do you handle $u(t)$?
I didn't find anything so far and I'd appreciate every hint that helps me figuring it out. (:

Comment: If $u$ depends on the current state and accumulated quantities, you might need to add some components to the state to account for such accumulation. If $u$ is computed from previous states you might need to switch to delay-differential equations (DDE). If $u$ is piecewise interpolated, you need to insert $u(t_n+c_iΔt)$.

Comment: Actually, the control input $u$ is a function of the (current) state $x$, i.e. $u(t) = u(x(t))$. Hence, $f(t, x(t), u(t)) = f(t, x(t), u(x(t))$. Therefore, one can also write $f(t, x(t), u(t)) = f(t, x(t))$. Please correct me if I'm wrong! 
Following that thought, when discretizing this system, I'd write "x[t_{n+1}] = f(t_n, x[t_n], u[t_n]) =  f(t_n, x[t_n], u[x[t_n]]) = f(t_n, x[t_n])$. Thus $u$ depends on the previous state? I'm kinda confused tbh. Can anyone give me a hint?
@LutzLehmann

Comment: That still remains the question. If $u(t)=g(x(t))$, the control depends immediately and directly only on the current state, then the ODE gets changed to $x'=F(t,x)$ with $F(t,x)=f(t,x,g(x))$ and the intermediate points for the stages of the RK method get computed accordingly. More realistically the control can have memory effects, delays, external influences which would require interpolation and some form of book-keeping. All these scenarios are possible and get discussed, so you need to be very clear what your situation is.